# Changing I/O buffer for a Windows Client

Tags: c#, windows, logging, buffer, buffer-overflow

I have a Windows software that maintains a log file while running. However, the update frequency of the log file is very low. However, if we increase the usage of the software, the update frequency of the log file speeds up.

I have a hypothesis that the logger of the software is storing the data in a buffer, and dumps it into the log file when the buffer fills up.

As the usage increases, the buffer fills up quicker and the dumps happen at a faster pace. According to the response provided by Software Support, the software is using fopen() and fwrite() to write the log file. The programmer could manually flush it with fflush() and fclose(), but since I don't have access to source code, I'd like to do it externally.

Is there a way to fill up the buffer externally, or reduce the buffer size, forcing the software to update the files quicker, even with low usage?

If not, is there some other way to get the desired result?

OS: Windows 10

Language of the Software: C# or C++

Comment: The methods mentioned are common in C++ development. The equivalent in C# within .NET would be the Stream or StreamReader classes's methods, like `Stream.Flush()` and `Stream.Close()`. Is the language of the software actually C#?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it is C# or C++, but this was the response of the developer. He refused to tell me anything further. Edited the question to reflect this. Thank you

Comment: You could try to write the log file to a removable drive, e.g. a flash drive. Maybe Windows flushes data faster to the physical disk if it's marked as removable.